# How does docker port mapping work on windows?

Tags: windows, port-forwarding, docker, ports

As far as I understood, it uses iptables on Linux and it allows to forward traffic not only by ip but also by port.

Now, in case of windows we have docker running in WSL2. Image name is docker-desktop. It has assigned ip address and exposes some ports. I can reach this VM through virtual adapter in windows.

On my machine it is

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2111:6704:7dea:56d5%49
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.176.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Also I can connect to those ports on my localhost. How does docker do it? Does it run a proxy for every port? I guess you can't forward traffic by ip + port in windows, so there should be some other mechanism.

Comment: “I guess you can't forward traffic by ip + port in windows” – sure you can, using `netsh interface portproxy`. That’s probably not what Docker uses though. There’s also some WSL 2 magic regarding `localhost`.

Comment: @DanielB It would be a proxy, not packets forwarding. I.e. it will establish separate connection to the endpoint and original ip address will be replaced by proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a
[Hyper-V Virtual Switch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-virtual-switch/hyper-v-virtual-switch).
It's not a proxy.

It is a virtual network adapter that looks to Windows identical to
any physical adapter.
The difference is that its driver is part of Hyper-V, and it handles
all packets that are sent to/from the adapter.

Packets destined to outside of the computer will be sent via the
real physical adapter of the computer and answers received via the
established connection.

Comment: Thanks, the question was about ports forwarding. I can access ports exposed by container at the localhost i.e. localhost:8080. Obviously, somehow it should be forwarded to the container, one option could be a proxy but I doubt it is used in that case.

Comment: There is no proxy, the virtual adapter receives all packets, no matter the port. It's the same as if you had two network cards in the computer.

Comment: Can you elaborate please, if I send the packet to the localhost:8080 in what scenario virtual adapter will receive this packet?

Comment: In all scenarios, all ports. Every adapter has a driver that does all the work. It's the same for this virtual adapter.

Comment: Traffic to `localhost` never leaves over any network adapter, hence the question.

Comment: @DanielB: This isn't localhost. It's IP 172.30.176.1.

Comment: OP said many times they're connecting to `localhost`, *not* some local-network IP address.

Comment: This would be the case if the subject is Docker, not VM. But then the virtual switch shouldn't be the subject. Perhaps there's some confusion here, although the question was what was the switch.